# How to convert Object list into a map of <String, List<String>>?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list of users

`Collection<User> userList = groupManager.getUserList(groupName);`

Not knowing the Java-Streams API that well, I want to map them into a map as follows: the key would be the user key, and the value would be a list the User object's other properties.

```
Map<String, List<String>> userDsiplayData = userList.stream()
     .collect(Collectors.toMap(User::getKey, **.......**))
```

I tried to replace **..... ** with `Arrays.asList(User::getUsername(), User::getDisplayName(), User::getEmail())` or similar constructs but I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use a lambda:

```
Map<String, List<String>> userDsiplayData = userList.stream()
     .collect(Collectors.toMap(User::getKey, 
         user -> List.of(user.getUsername(), user.getDisplayName(), user.getEmail()))
```

And by the way, your `Arrays.asList(User::getUsername(), User::getDisplayName(), User::getEmail())` piece is wrong - you try to return a list of method handles, rather than a mapping function (besides the fact that it's not syntactically correct - parentheses do not belong there).

Comment: With Java 9 or higher, you can also use `List.of(...)` instead of `Arrays.asList(..)`, with the added benefit that the list is immutable (instead of only fixed size).

Answer (score 2):

In your case the collect should be like this:

```
.collect(Collectors.toMap(
        User::getKey, 
        u -> Arrays.asList(u.getUsername(), u.getDisplayName(), u.getEmail())));
```

---

You can also create a custom method which return the expected List of fields in User class:

```
public class User {
    private String key;
    private String username;
    private String displayName;
    private String email;

    // getters setters

    public List<String> getUserInfo() {
        return Arrays.asList(username, displayName, email)));
    }
}
```

and then you can call it by using method reference like this:

```
.collect(Collectors.toMap(User::getKey, User::getUserInfo));
```